# The empty path didn't match any of these:

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

i am using python 3.8 and getting error when i launch server:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in djangoProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

polls/
admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

my polls/urls.py:

```
   from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

my djangoProject/urls.py:

```
  from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url("polls/", include('polls.urls')),
    url("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: You caN access it through `127.0..0.1:8000/polls/`, not `/` itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The root urls contains two items: `polls/` and `admin/`. This thus means that if you visit the root URL (`127.0.0.1:8000/`), it will not trigger any view, since no view has been "attached" to that URL pattern. You thus will have visit a page to trigger the view, or change the URL patterns to enable visiting the `index` view if you visit the root URL.

## Option 1: visit `/polls/`

You can visit the page by visiting:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
```

## Option 2: link `index` to the root URL

You can change the URL patterns to trigger `index` when visiting the root URL with:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    #   ↓↓ empty string
    url('', include('polls.urls')),
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```